After 3000 grit sand paper, do I go straight to 3500 polish or start with 1000 cut compound?
I want to remove the scratches on a clear peace of plastic. First I tried with polish (1000 2500 3500 - something like that), it did add some shine and removed some scratches but lots of scratches, even not so deep ones were sill there. I used foam pad and wool pad on my drill.
I thought, that these paint polishes are too weak for plastic, so I did a sanding process (800 then 2000 and 3000). The surface is now milky or cloudy.
I hand polished with 3500 polish, but not much happened.
Do I need to start over with cutting compound and worm my way up to polish or is it simply not going to work with paind polish at all?
Why does 3000 grit sand paper make things cloudy, but 3000 paint polish makes them shiney?
Will 5000 sand paper make it shiney or does the last stap need to be a pad?

I had same problem after all the other sanding was done   after cutting  and using the heavier grit ,the clear plastic was crazy milky looking.  i sanded homeade pic plate for my daughters 68' electric guitar i used 4000 grit and clean water ...it took alot of time  but the  conbination  did in fact work very well  ..you can try 3000 but ofcourse depends on type of plastic  but use the clean water while sanding and milk be gone

Thanks, what do you mean by clear water?
